# I need to CALCULATE() the total number of hours throughout the years, but what I what I get is a ridiculous number

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate the total of hours from the table 'Time Report[HH'] reardless of the date. The problem is that the result is much higher that what it actually is (4774 vs 68K (named REALESV2)).
Also, you can see how the curve drops after december :(

[image: Power BI picture] picture showing just 2022
[image: Power BI picture 2] picture showing 2022 and 2023

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please see [ask]. We need code, not images.

Comment: It's hard to advice - it's not clear what's going on with you data model/report. I'd try `Max()` instead of `Lastdate()`. `Lastdate()` returns a table, but you need a scalar value for filtering.